# running pgadmin4 in docker with pre-configured servers

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

I'd love to run pgadmin4 in our infrastructure in a way, that postgres servers would be preconfigured during docker build/1.st start.

I've tried to modify the internaly used `/var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db` sqlite DB on the 1.st start, which however results in an error in the UI (once selecting the particular postgres server:

> definition of service "" not found

I've tried following:

Directory structure:

```
find ./  -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'       
|____
|____dump
| |____servergroup.csv
| |____server.csv
| |____import_db.sh
|____Dockerfile
```

Where `Dockerfile` is:

```
cat Dockerfile
# rebuild:
# docker build -t pgadmin4:3.0-custom .
# run:
# docker run --rm -it -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin -p8081:80 docker build -t pgadmin4:3.0-custom

FROM dpage/pgadmin4:3.0

COPY dump/ /dump

RUN \
    apk add --no-cache sqlite && \
    chmod +x /dump/import_db.sh && \
    # re rely on the current entrypoint.sh impl
    sed -i '/python run_pgadmin.py/a   \/dump\/import_db.sh' /entrypoint.sh && \
    cat /entrypoint.sh
```

In fact it just modifies the https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/pkg/docker/entrypoint.sh to run `import_db.sh` script on the 1.st start.

Where `dump/import_db.sh` is:

```
cat dump/import_db.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo ".tables" | sqlite3 -csv /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db

# remove header and `1,1,Servers` entry (would cause duplicates)
cat /dump/servergroup.csv | sed '1d' | grep -v 1,1,Servers > /tmp/servergroup.in.csv
echo "csv servergroup:"
cat /tmp/servergroup.in.csv

echo "DB servergroup:"
sqlite3 -csv -header /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db "select * from servergroup;"
echo ".import /tmp/servergroup.in.csv servergroup" | sqlite3 -csv /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db

# remove header
cat /dump/server.csv | sed '1d' > /dump/server.in.csv
echo "csv server:"
cat /dump/server.in.csv

echo "DB server:"
sqlite3 -csv -header /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db "select * from server;"
echo ".import /dump/server.in.csv server" | sqlite3 -csv /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
```

Csv files contents:

```
cat dump/server.csv 
id,user_id,servergroup_id,name,host,port,maintenance_db,username,password,role,ssl_mode,comment,discovery_id,hostaddr,db_res,passfile,sslcert,sslkey,sslrootcert,sslcrl,sslcompression,bgcolor,fgcolor,service
1,1,2,servername,localhost,5432,postgres,postgres,"",,prefer,,,"","",,<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.crt,<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.key,,,0,,,

cat dump/servergroup.csv
id,user_id,name
2,1,my-group
1,1,Servers
```

Any idea how to fix my error? Or of any other approach that could provide me the pre-configured pgadmin4 docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks this change the `service` column value to an empty string instead of NULL.

Can you try updating the value of `service` column to NULL

```
sqlite> UPDATE server SET service = NULL;
```

commit the changes and Restart pgAdmin4 & try again connecting to that server.

Answer (score 13):

The current version of image dpage/pgadmin is 4.24. This version has [support](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html) for external configuration of server definition list (servers.json):

```
{
    "Servers": {
        "test": {
            "Name": "test",
            "Group": "Servers",
            "Port": 5432,
            "Username": "postgres",
            "Host": "postgres",
            "SSLMode": "prefer",
            "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
        }
    }
}
```

Volume binding can be configured as below:

```
volumes:
    - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

First time container is started server groups and servers will be configured automaticaly.

UPD. JSON format has more fields which are optional. It's important that [password can not be imported/exported](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_servers.html#json-format) in such way due to the obvious security reasons.

Comment: Looks like passwords can't be imported/exported via the json, which is incredibly disappointing and makes this feature incomplete.

These docs gives more info on the servers.json file - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_servers.html